# Field's name with numbers: why not?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

I have tried to create field in TOC called with numbers with python. But, it has a problem: it couldn't do it because name's of fields are numbers. It is strange for me. When I do new field in shape file with mouse and put name field with number I haven't had problem.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include a Python snippet that shows us exactly how you are trying to do this, please ?

Answer (score 5):

In just about every language and database in creation, identifiers are defined as {alpha}[{alphanumeric_or_underscore}*]. The root reason has to do with numeric values being expected to start with numeric symbols (or a hyphen).

ArcGIS is no different on this score. The standard way to have numeric fields is to prefix them all with the same character or string.